# How to make image load smooth in safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome, safari

I need to change background image on hover, I am preloading images through Javascript on document ready,
Now the thig is its working fine in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari it takes time to load. So is there any way so I can make it smooth like Firefox ? Moreover, Images are heavy in size approximate in Mbs.

This is what I did to preload and change image on hover

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Set Default home page background
    if(defaultBGimage != "" && defaultBGimage != null && typeof(defaultBGimage) != "undefined"){
        $.backstretch(defaultBGimage, {centeredY: false});
    }
    // Pre-load images 
    function preloadImages(srcs) {
        if (!preloadImages.cache) {
            preloadImages.cache = [];
        }
        var img;
        for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = srcs[i];
            preloadImages.cache.push(img);
        }
    }

    preloadImages(catBGimages); // Pass array of images to preload it 

    jQuery(".level1-cat").hover(function(){ // on hover change home page background image
        if(catBGimages[jQuery(this).data('id')] != null && catBGimages[jQuery(this).data('id')] != "null" && catBGimages[jQuery(this).data('id')] != "" && typeof(catBGimages[jQuery(this).data('id')]) != "undefined"){
            $.backstretch(catBGimages[jQuery(this).data('id')], {centeredY: false});
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which makes preload images quickly try this may help u ..

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

Comment: are u able to load all images using my code just check with a console..if its then issue is with something else..reply after checking..

Comment: yeah its loading but there isn't any improvement in performance

Comment: Ultimately its same I am creating element by JS and in your case its through jQuery.

Comment: yeah few are above 1 mb. and other near by 800 to 900 kbs